# Typescript mapped type unexpected value signature

Tags: arrays, typescript

Why does Array.push has signature `A & B` instead of expected `A | B`

```js
type A = { a: unknown };
type B = { b: unknown };

type MyType = {
  numbers: A;
  strings: B;
};

type Arrayed<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][];
};

type MyArrayed = Arrayed<MyType>;

const arrayed: MyArrayed = {
  numbers: [],
  strings: [],
};

function push<K extends keyof MyArrayed>(key: K, value: MyArrayed[K][0]) {
  // why does .push has A & B signature?
  arrayed[key].push(value);

  // this fails too
  arrayed[key] = [...arrayed[key]]
}
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBXAdgaxwHsB3HKAXwG4AoUSKAIQWSgCNNcCSyrrbxoAWRAAVAcyTUoUHFgC2rCACcAzphg1pK4EoCWOAOZrGNXv3owlS1CAgATADwiAfBKlQA2gGko+qHggQQgAzKBEAXUwRb3CPcNMacyEQS2tbO2ZUm3sHYTFIZ0SAY0IcbTQrbLtMYSz0t2lZBWVjOIAad209Q1bwjrNg3CLgXVKoMCwVAAsHHwgAD2AIHDsVf0CQqFrK9OcACgCQTC82qAA3VAAbLAgalJ37GI8ABnCASmR3AHovqGIpkBQOyECBrAB0E2mUCmqDWcAAZIwoCpdAYcKhgFglBAAPzuVAPOweQ7hCGTKZ7C7XCBvRLSH5QYBTXRrYKoXSXNbAQiEfGE4mBcLMDxg0UEtKPEnhajkIA)

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler can't keep track of the correlation between `key` and `value` and expands both to uncorrelated union types. See answer to the question this duplicates; translating that answer here gives [this](https://tsplay.dev/zwO6dW) code.

Comment: Your specific question ("why `&` and not `|`") might be answered by [this handbook link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) (which is linked in the other question too)